# Remove existing ServiceConnect authentication credentials

Tags: external-calls, webservices, serviceexecute

I am working on a project using the BingSearch ServiceConnect (`ServiceConnect["BingSearch"]`)
and I would like to use a different authentication key then what I initially provided (which was asked when I first ran the service).

Does anyone have any idea on how to remove my current auth key and provide a new one?

As an example, if you have never authenticated before, and run the following code, there will be a pop-up window. I want to get to that again.

```
 ServiceExecute["BingSearch", 
  "Search", {"Query" -> "NASA", 
   "SearchType" -> "Web", 
   "Country" -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
   "Language" -> Entity["Language", "English"], 
   "Site" -> Except["wikipedia.org"], MaxItems -> 10}]
```

Thanks!